# Exercise of Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

For $f$ in dual space, there exists $x$ with norm $1$ and $f(x)=‖f‖$ if space is reflexive. Use this fact to show that $\ell^ 1 $ is not reflexive.

Let $\alpha = (\alpha_{k}) \in \ell^{\infty}.$ Consider $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{k} x_{k}, \quad x=\left(x_{k}\right) \in \ell^1.$ In this case, $|| f || = || \alpha ||_{\infty}.$ I want to look for $\alpha \in \ell^{\infty}$ appropriate such that $ f (x) \ne || f ||, \forall x$ with $||x||_1 =1.$ But I haven't been able to find it yet. Can you give me an idea please?

Comment: James theorem states that a normed space is reflexive iff every bounded  functional attains its norm, that is, for all $f \in X^*$ there exists $x \in B_X$ such that $f(x)=||f||$

Comment: @SonGohan You are thinking of the fact that for all $x\in X$ there is some $f\in X'$ such that $f(x)=\lVert x\rVert$, but this is the other way around.

Comment: You are right, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

Take $\alpha =((1-\frac 1 n))$. There is no $(x_n)$ of norm $1$ such that $\sum (1-\frac 1n) x_n=1$. Can you show this?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it.